# MediaWiki: Where to put custom css classes?

Tags: css, mediawiki, visual-editor

I'm extending an MediaWiki and it's *VisualEditor-plugin* by adding custom data structures. Those also need css classes. I've figured how to add them to the VisualEditor, but as soon as I leave it *and refresh* (that's strange, when I save the changes made in VisualEditor the css-effects are visible in the normal view until I refresh), the css effects disappear.

I'm saving the css-classes in an *VisualEditor-directory*, so I understand that it does not necessarily has to be shown outside of it. But I sadly do not know where to put them. I've seen some classes are added in `commonPrint.css` in *mediawiki.legacy*, but adding the classes there didn't help sadly (although they show up when I check the source via Chrome DevTools).

Comment: i believe you can create MediaWiki:MyStyles.css, but i'm not sure how to apply it to pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For screen [[MediaWiki:Common.css]] and for printer [[MediaWiki:Print.css]].

Answer (score 0):

and then use https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CSS to apply your CSS to whichever individual pages you want.